# New question to get more detail?

Tags: discussion

We have a great community wiki that defines many of the terms used in lenses here: [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

I recently asked the question: [What is USM, and what are its pros and cons?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16951/what-does-usm-mean) I asked it not because I didn't know what the acronym stood for, but because I wanted to understand the details, reasons why you would want it, types of it, pros/cons, etc.

The issue I am wondering about is if we have this great community wiki with definitions for lens terminology, **is it OK to ask further questions to get the details, or do we want to turn the community wiki that is already very long into an even longer** answer?

My next example is the terminology DO, yes it defines it as Diffractive Optics in the wiki, but I have no idea what that means, and I don't see another question that asks all of the details of it.

Answer (score 3):

Detailed questions are certainly welcome as long as the question is not a duplicate.

The examples you have given are great ways to expand the knowledge available on the site, and would be great additions.

I think that these should be different questions, and could be linked to in the wiki, but should not be included.  The purpose of that question was not to explain **the details** of every single technology, it was to explain the specific **terminology** that is used to describe a lens model.